# Custom Advanced Google Analytics Fiter: URI --> Campaign

Tags: filter, google-analytics, uri

I've a client with a print ad to domain.com/print-campaign-uri/

I want to create an advanced filter in Analytics so that /print-campaign-uri/ outputs to 'Print Campaign Name' as a Campaign (filters a uri and renames it to a campaign)

**Right now I have:**

Field A -> Extract A        |  Request URI     | /print-campaign-uri/
Field B -> Extract B        |  Request URI     |  - 
Output To -> Constructor    |  Campaign Name   |  Print Campaign Name

What am I missing and/or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

Use:

Output To -> Constructor | Campaign Name | $A1

Also remember, don't apply this filter to the main profile. Make a secondary profile to see this data with the filter.